# Is it better to give reference when I use the same sentence which state a fact or I must paraphrase it?

Tags: publications, citations, plagiarism

I am new to the concept of plagiarism and also how to give reference in an article. As my English is not very well, I may use some sentences borrowed from other papers. But they may just define a term which is common in the literature. For example, consider the following sentence:

> Any procedure that aims at extracting information (structured data) from unstructured (free text) or semi-structured data source is called wrapper.

Or

> Web Data Extraction has many applications in different areas including Business and Competitive Intelligence, crawling of Social Web platforms, Bio-Informatics and so on

I copied them from another publication, I did minor changes in their wordings, however, in the second sentence I may count other applications of the system.

I would like to know, should I use a reference for them? Because I thought reference is mostly for the related works or background of the research and they might be some facts or definitions!

---

My question may seem similar to [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/19418/is-it-permissible-to-use-somebody-elses-words-without-quotations-to-describe), however the answer of this question solves my problem to some extent, but in this question I mainly asked about the role of citation. I think I shouldn't cite a fact or something that is very common. In such cases I can't understand the logic behind avoiding a similar definition or sentence! how do you explain that.

Comment: i strongly suggest that you consult an introductory book on scientific writing.

Answer (score 1):

1. You **must** provide a reference to each and every of your sources. otherwise you are plagiarizing.
2. If you quote verbatim ("copy"), you **must** provide a reference and put the quote in quotation marks or indicate the quotation by indentation. otherwise you are plagiarizing.
3. You **can** provide references beyond that, for example if you feel they contain relevant background material.

Comment: I think you could add paraphrasing to this list, as it seems to be what the OP is asking about.